# Repair / get data from corrupted SQLite file

Tags: php, sqlite, corruption

My applications uses SQLite for data storage. Everything was ok, but one day someone corrupted the data file and now application cannot read it. I cannot understand what is wrong specifically, but there are two things I know:
1)    `$result = sqlite_query($query,$db_path);`
When this code runs with the old backup (which, by the way, doesn't contain all the data), everything is fine, `$result` becomes a correct value. When it runs with the corrupted file, `$result` becomes `null`.
2) I opened this corrupted SQLite file in notepad and it seems to be fine (its structure is just like the structure of the old one).

The only idea I have is to parse that corrupted file. Where can I get SQLite files specification? Or maybe there is another way?

Comment: If you are using linux or have access to linux then install "sqliteman" and open the database file in it and issue the query manually on corrupted database file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I use Windows...

Answer (score 0):

There's a command line tool called *sqlite3* that allows you to manage SQLite databases.
Once started, use ".help" to see available options. I haven't tried it on corrupted databases, so I have no idea how it will fare.

One idea would be to look at the schema and *dump* tables from the sqlite databases, one at a time until you hit the table that is stored in the corrupted parts of your file.

```
cristi:FoodBrowser diciu$ sqlite3 FoodBrowser.sql 
SQLite version 3.6.12
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .help
.backup ?DB? FILE      Backup DB (default "main") to FILE
[..]
```

Comment: I tried once. It basically creates a copy of the DB with all the valid info. So there may be information missing.

Comment: That corrupted database is in the SQLite 2.1 format. I found such a tool only for SQLite 3. Is there one for 2.1?